# Configure win10 as rdp client only

Tags: windows, windows-10, terminal, remote-desktop, active-directory

I have a company with AD RDP terminial server (win 2016) running.
People use a win10 computer to sign into the RDP server using the standard windows RDP client.

I have been able to auto connect to the server after user sign in, so that helps, but I haven't found a solution to the following problem:

A user signs into PC1 and the windows RDP client starts automatically and connects to the terminal server using the user's AD credentials.
so far so good.
Later the user sits at another desk, signs into PC2 and is connected to the teminal server again automatically.
On PC1 a popup shows saying the RDP session has ended.
The user is still loged into PC1 but there is no RDP client running.

If another user wants to use PC1 he or she first needs to switch users before geting to work.

Is there a way around this? Is there a way to sign out a user once the RDP session ends? So the next user is presented with a login screen.
Or is there a way to configure win 10 as a rdp client only, disabeling stand alone usage?

Hope someone can help me!

Robert.

Comment: If you use the computer only for RDP why do you let the users log-on on the PC? Configure it to kiosk-mode with only rdp client allowed. Then you only have the RDP logon.

Comment: Have you enabled the "Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single remote session" Group Policy setting, probably in
Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Connections.

Answer (score 0):

you could configure session timeouts via group policy, a great sample can be found [here](https://www.top-password.com/blog/automatically-log-off-idle-remote-desktop-sessions-in-windows/)

#### Idle session limit

```
Specify the maximum amount of time that an active Remote Desktop Services 
session can be idle (without user input) before the session is automatically       
disconnected or ended. The user receives a warning two minutes before the 
session is disconnected or ended, which allows the user to press a key or 
move the mouse to keep the session active.
```

#### End a disconnected session

```
Specify the maximum amount of time that a disconnected user session is kept   
active on the RD Session Host server. If you specify "Never," the user's 
disconnected session is maintained for an unlimited time. When a session is 
in a disconnected state, running programs are kept active even though the 
user is no longer actively connected.
```

Both of these setting can be set in Computer Configuration or User Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

it's just a suggestion. I have not tested, but try to run after logging in .bat file with the command mstsc.exe [params…] and logoff.exe in next line.
Write if this idea worked.